# How to dereference a pointer in ASM data section?

Tags: c, assembly, symbols, extern, dereference

I have a C code that declares a global pointer and initializes it. Something like this:

```
my_type* var = malloc(...)
```

When I declare var as an extern symbol in ASM x86 I get a reference to the pointer, i.e. a double pointer, which is really inconvenient because whenever I want to access the content I have to do something like this:

```
extern var
mov ax, [var]
mov dx, [ax]
```

I want to get a symbol in ASM that holds the value returned by malloc, i.e a pointer to my_type as I have in the C code.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of the ASM code?

Comment: You mean `&var` is a double-pointer?  So you have to load twice to access the malloced memory?  Yes, that's what happens when you store malloc return values in memory instead of passing them in registers.

Comment: I have added a code sample in ASM. I would like to avoid using brackets twice!

Comment: @NicolásHertzulis There isn't really a way to avoid that as I explained in my answer. That's just how assembly works. The first load fetches the pointer, the second fetches the datum pointed to.

Answer (score 3):

That's how variables work. The value of a symbol (i.e. its address) cannot change at runtime, which is why symbols generally resolve to the address of a datum and not the datum itself. There is no way to get the exact behaviour you desire because the address `malloc` returns cannot be known at link time.

If you want to avoid dealing with variables containing pointers, consider creating an array in static storage instead.